# Who designed exceptions?

Tags: history, exceptions

Where did exceptions and exception handling come from?

I like how .NET uses it, I like how C++ supports it (but libraries unfortunately use return code or is written in C instead). I know its pretty much standard in all new languages, but who designed it first or where did it come from?

Is C++ the first language to use it? I don't know of any other that is older.

Comment: Apparently, Plankalkül had exception handling in the 1940's, though the first compiler didn't exist until about 50 years later. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plankalk%C3%BCl)

Comment: You could say that C++ was the first not ivory tower language that introduced exceptions to the masses. But the concept has been around since the beginning (or a long time, take your pick).

Comment: Looking for someone to strangle? I'm kidding...

Comment: Should we take into account the influences from hardware exceptions?

Comment: @rwong: i never heard of hw exceptions.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: My jaw just hit the floor. I knew of Konrad Zuse, but didn't know that. He is the father of us all.

Comment: Rant about return values as opposed to exceptions isn't really valid :P. Some of us prefer return error values (the go implementation of them is really nice!), but could still find this question interesting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Raising and trapping exceptions has been around for quite a time. 
>   This site says exceptions were introduced in PL/I:
>   http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/CS302/98S/Outlines/outline.02.html
>
> which was in 1967, according to this page (includes an extensive but
>   not exhaustive chart of computer languages and features):
>   http://community.borland.com/article/0,1410,22741,00.html
>
> Many languages picked up this technique -- ADA, ALGOL, FORTRAN, ML [...]

Quoted from [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=26101).

Wikipedia has more detail about [exception handling in PL/1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I#On-Units_and_exception_handling). That page also refers to PL/1 being the first. Of course, this is no scientific proof :-)

As for who in person designed PL/1, the article mentions no names, only various committees at IBM.

Comment: Execptions in PL/I were really specific types of events.  You could define and raise your own events and write event handlers to catch them.  ISTR there was some support for this in some system facilities (VTAM?), so you could actually write event-driven programs.

Comment: Can you think of any languages prior to C++ which provided a facility for orderly cleanup during stack unwinding?

Comment: Exceptions in FORTRAN? Come on...

Answer (score 6):

Hof, Mössenböck and Pirkelbauer (in their 1997 paper *Zero-Overhead Exception Handling using Metaprogramming*) affirm that the concept of exceptions was suggested in the seventies, referring to John B. Goodenough's 1975 [*Exception handling: Issues and a proposed notation*](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~bec/courses/csci5535-s09/reading/goodenough-exceptions.pdf) paper in the *Communications of the ACM*.  In it he conflates modern exception handling with the general idea of registering callbacks, and his proposed notation looks more like modern Attribute metadata specifications than `try/catch`, but it (or at least its section 2) is a great overview of the state of exception handling in the mid-seventies.

Perhaps of note is also the `raise/rescue` mechanism in [Alef](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/2nd_edition/papers/alef/ug), which one can view as a primitive form of `catch` blocks, lest we think they sprang fully-formed from Stroustroup's brow like Athena from Zeus's.

Comment: did you read [prior answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/40352/31260)? It dates exceptions 1967: **eight years earlier** than the date you refer to

Comment: I did, but I was trying to trace some of the history between the appearance of exceptions in C++ and the ON CONDITION statements in PL/I.  I guess my addition was unwelcome?

Comment: Actually, many papers on exception handling refer to goodenough for the overview, discussion and its influence on modern exception mechanism -- its reasonable to consider it seminal. On the other hand, "exception handling" has distinct semantics in many languages, and I would expect this to be specially true before Goodenough's publication. With this in mind, a conservative answer to this question could just as well trace it back to a conditional jump.

Comment: @gnat: Did you read the comment that traces the idea to the 1940's?  Even if that comment didn't exist, the question is "where did exceptions come from?", not "name the earliest date when exceptions were used".

Comment: @MichaelShaw the answer I refer to has been posted at the same time as comment you mention, and it also attempts to address the question asked ("being the first"). As opposed to it, this post failed to acknowledge apparently visible earlier evidence and didn't even tried to address the question

Comment: @gnat: The question asks multiple questions.  This answer answers one of the questions that was repeated twice in the question: "where did it come from?".